# Dynamic shading of gradient in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a cshtml page with some Div elements. These div elements are colored with a gradient as specified in the style classes. I also added a hover class which turns the div color slightly lighter, in effect mimicking the effect of a button and the hovering over it. The divs ultimately are used to contain text received from the MVC controller.

What I would like to do is some way in jquery perhaps to dynamically change the shading of a set of divs. I will specify the set to be red (#FF0000), but the rest of the divs in the set should then go a shade lighter. Something similar to the W3 color picker's 'Shades' block http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

Here is a jsfiddle with what I more or less need to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/ezxkf3qL/1/

You will note that I have 2 css classes defining the color gradients, 'red1' and 'red2'. If I have 6 divs within 3 sets it means I need to build 18 different color classes and their respective hover methods.

Ideally I would like to have one color class and one hover method class for each set. Then jquery would take the color and dynamically change the 'red' class's gradient colors for each element so as to get the same type of effect as in my example.

I have tried something like this also:

```
var list = $("div.col").find(".get");

var step = 100;

list.each(function(i, e) {
   var shade = i * step;
   $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255, " + shade + "," + shade + ")");
});
```

This does change the shading, but with 6 elements it kinda gets too light or doesn't distinguish the different shading enough. Also this does not solve my problem with the gradient.

This same principle would apply to the coloring of buttons or whichever other element. Maybe there is jquery that could solve all of this at the same time which I am not aware of. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a shot, and here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/cn6096ck/).

I assumed that you would do this for the 'red' (#ff0000) hue only and the spectrum going from red to lighter red. The fiddle above is using the webkit syntax, you can modify the code to fit your needs.

```
var base= 0;
var others=0;
var otherbase = 100;
var step= 15;
list.each(function(i, e) {
   $(this).css("background", "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb("+ base +","+others+","+others+") 0%,#FF0000 100%) ");

    if(base<60)
        base=base+30;
    else if(base<200)
        base= base + 15;
    else{
     base= base + 25;
        others=otherbase + step;

        otherbase=others;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/cn6096ck/), you should be able to test it now, sorry about that.

What the code does is that it counts how many `.get` divs there are and applies the gradient spectrum starting from black to red to white. The variance of the shades depends on how many `.get` divs there are (the fewer, the larger the difference).

For the hover, I assumed that you only wanted to lighten the shade of the hovered div. So I created a pseudo-element that would only appear on hover and act as a semi-transparent white overlay, please see CSS code below:

```
.get:hover:before {
    content:"";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

This requires jQuery by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply KiiroSora09. Your fiddle didn't run for me to see the effect, but  I have combined your one line with @Nikhil's. You can see that updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ezxkf3qL/4/. But as I mentioned in the question also, I need the same type of effect for a hover class/method. So when I hover over the div I need it to be lighter to replicate the effect of a button.

Comment: @Bester I updated my answer, though it might be too late.

Comment: Wow this is perfect and exactly what I need! Thanks a mil @KiiroSora09

Answer (score 3):

I tried what you want, see the fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/ezxkf3qL/2/" and screenshot:

[image]

Here I interrogated the color changes using [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp). So I used the following algorithm to achieve the result, the JS code is:

var list = $("div.col").find(".get");

```
var base= 0;
var others=0;
var otherbase = 100;
var step= 15;
list.each(function(i, e) {
   $(this).css("background-color", "rgb("+ base +","+others+","+others+")");
    if(base<60)
        base=base+30;
    else if(base<200)
        base= base + 15;
    else{
     base= base + 25;
        others=otherbase + step;

        otherbase=others;
    }
});
```

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="get mydiv1"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv2"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv3"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv4"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv5"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv6"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv7"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv8"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv9"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv10"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv11"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv12"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv13"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv14"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv15"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv16"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv17"></div>
    <div class="get mydiv18"></div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

To get darker shades, keep changing `R(RED)` values and keep others as 0. Then after Red crosses 200, start increasing the other `G` and `B` values beyond a base value say 100. Continue using this and you will get the following result as shown in fiddle and image.

To make the hove effect use jquery `.hover()` as:

```
(".get").hover(function(){
//  change background here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nikhil. I have combined your answer with a line from @KiiroSora09. See the updated fiddle as to what I was looking for https://jsfiddle.net/ezxkf3qL/4/. I can work with this to solve the first part of my question. But it doesn't solve the second part of the hover over the div. You will note now that there is no more animation if you hover over the different divs. How can I add the hover function now?

Comment: You need to use .hover() of jquery for the same, inside logic has to be something that needs to be worked out. Edited the answer if you wish to see syntax.